# How to add multiple counts of large lists

Tags: clojure

If I do a simple version
    `(+ (count [1 2 3 4]) (count [1 2 3 4]))`
I get the correct answer `8`

But when I use the large scale version from my program that could potentially have `count` equaling 100,000 it no longer functions.  combatLog is a 100,000 line log file.

```
   (let [rdr (BufferedReader. (FileReader. combatLog))]
        (+  (count (filter (comp not nil?) (take 100000 (repeatedly #(re-seq #"Kebtiz hits" (str (.readLine rdr)))))))
            (count (filter (comp not nil?) (take 100000 (repeatedly #(re-seq #"Kebtiz misses" (str (.readLine rdr)))))))
            )
        )
```

In this case, it returns only the value of the first count.  I am trying to figure out either why `+` and `count` aren't working in this case, or another way to sum the total number of elements in both lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you are reading from the same reader in two places. It seems that the first line consumes the whole reader and the second one gets no lines to filter. Notice that each call to `.readLine` moves the position in the input file.

I guess you wanted to do something like:

```
(with-open [reader (clojure.java.io/reader combatLog]
  (->> reader
    (line-seq)
    (filter #(re-seq #"Kebtiz hits|Kebtiz misses"))
    (count)))
```

Using `with-open` will make sure your file handle will be closed and resources won't leak. I also combined your two separate regular expressions into one.

Comment: Okay, so I am starting with an empty file by the time I get to the search for misses.  I should have assumed that from java/C file reading, thank you.